# Android GUI Layout

Tags: android, image, user-interface, button, android-edittext

I am currently trying to work out how to align certain elements within my Android app's GUI.
Please see the image link below, the first layout is the current one, and the second is what I am aiming for.
Currently, I am using two linear Layouts. I have tried to use relative and table layouts for the right hand buttons and EditText, but always the EditText is shrunk, or overflows the tablet's screen size.

Thanks for your help!

Image Link: (http://postimage.org/image/pptkdkomx/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.5" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5" android:text="Button1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"  android:text="Button2"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `RelativeLayout` and on your `EditText` use `android:layout_alignBottom="myImage"`

Answer (score 1):

Just brought together a quick template, you may need to fix + add your own attributes since I used only notepad:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50"/>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50">

        <LinearLayout 
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="50"/>

            <Button android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="50"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```